# Adjust div based on screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm building a page editor app (lite version of Canva)
My page div is in A4 and its 1277px.

It looks good on big screens but at small screens dont.

[image]

How I can transform page to be visible on smaller screens.

My solution:

```
.page {
  transform: perspective(100vh) translateZ(calc(100vh - 1300px));
  transform-origin: center top;
}
```

it  works good but its blur and I want max-height 1277px for div .page. Also I think its not supported by older browsers

Comment: Did you check media queries ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) like so to define your max-height e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .page {
    max-height: 1277px;
  }
}
```

However, it is better practice to use [relative lengths](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), because they scale better.

If you would like to check whether or not something is supported by an older browser, you could use the site 'Can I Use?'. For example, if you wanted to check if you can use media queries in older browsers, you would do this: https://caniuse.com/?search=media

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust div size according to screen size you can have 2 options

1. use media queries
2. use percentages width